Secret US reconnaissance aircraft more advanced then the SR 71 that is stolen from the US
Basically, this plane is stolen from the US by one of its pilots who plans to give it to the Russians.
Some of the things I remember are that the pilot was connected intravenously to the aircraft while piloting it.
The US sends an SR 71 to try and catch it.
Book was out in the early to late 90s.

Intravenously? What was that about?

Sounds a bit like a country-flipped Firefox.

Was the intravenous connection to facilitate extended recon flights, with alternating stimulants and sedatives?  Did the aircraft use active ECM to disguise its true location?  Finally, are you certain that the pilot was trying to steal it, or was it that after he ejected he made some bad decisions (leading to capture) due to the aftereffects of the drugs he had been subjected to over the multi-day flight?

The pilots family was under threat so he was delivering the plane to the Russians. He didn't eject that I can remember. The IV was for extended recon flights iirc.
